# Is different mute key action possible?

Tags: windows, keyboard

Can i change a mute key sometimes to mute on pressing and unmute on release so i can have musical fun when i watch videos? making a rhythm with the video soundtrack using mute as rest and video as a drum. in windows

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>Mute down</kbd> and
<kbd>Mute up</kbd>
to toggle the mute mode:

```
Volume_Mute::Send, {Volume_Mute}
Volume_Mute up::Send, {Volume_Mute}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: If somebody doesn't like the question, this is no reason to downvote answers.